# Navigation Bar Links not responsive

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, navigation, nav

I have currently added a navigation bar to a webpage I'm coding. The problem is, the links within the bar are unresponsive. I'm pretty sure it has to do with the `display: flex;`
in the CSS for the nav links; however, I can't get rid of it as I need the nav links to be in a straight line. This is what it currently looks like ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29Gl6.png)) . I have a navigation bar with a link in the home button but the link isn't responsive. When I take out the `display: flex;`, the link becomes responsive however the list ends up looking like this ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9METj.png)). They become stacked one atop the other. I would really appreciate it if someone could take a look at my code and point me in the right direction

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.title {
  height: 20vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  top: -60px;
  left: 400px;
}

.image-container {
  height: 768px;
  width: 768px;
  border: 10px solid black;
  position: relative;
  top: -165px;
}

.image-container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.transition-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;

}

.transition-image:hover {
  opacity: 1;

}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 8vh;
  background-color: #5d4954;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.logo {
  color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.nav-links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 30%;

}

.nav-links li {
  list-style: none;

}

.nav-links a {
  color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles.css">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav>
      <div class="logo">
        <h4>[Ayanfe]:)</h4>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav-links">
        <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gXkqy0b4M5g&ab_channel=DevEd">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Next</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <h1 class="title">Example Text</h1>
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="./Images/Image.jpg" alt="">
      <img class="transition-image" src="./Images/Gif.gif" alt="">
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you want to achieve. Because, yes it's overflowing when the viewport is too small. But how do you wanna solve it? Create a burger menu for mobile? You can check out [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) and define what should happen to your nav on a specific screensize.